# Quartz: How to remove a set of jobs when another job is started?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Is there a mechanism in Quartz to remove existing jobs when another job is started?  The reason I need to pause other jobs is because the new job requires all the resources to be available which is only true when other jobs aren't running.

**Here is an example:**

I have 2 Jobs: Job A and Job B

Job A runs through the day.
Job B is executed once every 24 hours.

Is there a way to remove or pause Job A while Job B is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your jobs implement `InterruptableJob`, then you can interrupt Job A from Job B by calling `interrupt(jobKey)` on the Quartz scheduler.

Javadocs:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/index.html

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#interrupt(org.quartz.JobKey)

Example:

https://github.com/elventear/quartz-scheduler/blob/master/distribution/examples/src/main/java/org/quartz/examples/example7/InterruptExample.java

Comment: How would Job B be aware of Job A's JobKey though?  When Job B is being executed, it has no scope of Job A.  The scheduler has scope of Job A but within Job B's execute function, it has no awareness of Job A.